How can I get my linear-gradient to look consistent on Chrome and Firefox
This is what it looks like on Chrome
This is what it looks like on Firefox
Here is my CSS chunk:
.color-legend {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(
      to right in oklch decreasing hue, 
      oklch(100% 0 9) 6% 6%, 
      oklch(0% 0.5 15) 93% 93%
    ); 
}

I need for them both to look like the Chrome version.
I tried using -moz-linear-gradient and I tried add multiple colors to the gradient but neither solved the issue

I've tried longer, shorter, increasing and decreasing in FF, Edge and Safari and each of them has interpreted things differently. Hope someone can say whether oklch is supposed to be working in this situation - I can't find any absolutely definitive reference.

Slightly more consistency if use hsl instead - Safari and Edge give the same results, FF not. Is it going round the color wheel a different way or something weird?

I don't know. It's very frustrating. The weird thing is that I'm using oklch on other parts of the site (not within a linear-gradient) and it's all working fine on the browsers I've tested.

Is this FF bug report https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1904106 relevant? It was from 2 months ago and I can’t see a resolution.

This looks very similar to what's happening with my issue. I bet they are related. Thanks!

Maybe try using RGBA colors? I tried the RGBA version for a simple span element, and it works for both chrome and Firefox. You could, of course, go to the "Inspect" option in both browsers and see how it is reading the style.
As for HSL, OKLCH interpolation is quite different from HSL interpolation, so any kind of fallback fails.
[EDIT]:
The only useful trick is to create or find a tool in html which can divide an OKLCH gradient into 2 to 10 RGB or HSL colors which you can then use normally. I am working on such a tool for all color types, and I will send a link as soon as it is ready. As for now just divide the given OKLCH gradient into 5 parts manually and then use it.
BTW,  the reason the gradient fails in Firefox is because Firefox's style reading system is a bit outdated; even if OKLCH is supported. This failure does not happen in Opera, Edge, or even Safari.

Do you have an example which gives the look the question wanted? Note it wanted decreasing as the hue parameter.

One way to use the decreasing hue olkch gradient would be to divide it into 2 to10 RGB parts; which is easily doable with a gradient tool on the internet or you could make such a tool yourself. I am working on one.
